# Flutter Dropdown with api - CircularProgressIndicator every time reload

Tags: flutter

I've this this dropdown

```
  Future<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>> add() async {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "0", child: Text("USA")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1", child: Text("Canada"))
    ];
    var url = Uri.http("localhost:8080","/province");
    var response = await http.get(url);
    return menuItems;
  }
  
  String selectedValue = "2";

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            FutureBuilder<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>>(
              future: add(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if (snapshot.hasData){
                  var data = snapshot.data!;
                  return DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedValue,
                    items: data.map((DropdownMenuItem<String> items) {
                      return items;
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String? value) { 
                      setState(() {
                          selectedValue = value;
                      });
                    }, 
                  );    
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is a function add that is used to populate Dropdown Widget an then call an API that take some time. How can i make dropdown replaced by a  CircularProgressIndicator every time add is called ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Future Builder will always be called this way and its wrong.

You can try this way :

```
 List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
const DropdownMenuItem(value: "0", child: Text("USA")),
const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1", child: Text("Canada"))


 ];
  bool loading=true;
  Future<List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>> add(value) async {
    setState(() {
      selectedValue=value;
      loading=true;
    });

    var url = Uri.http("localhost:8080","/province");
    var response = await http.get(url);
    setState(() {
      loading=false;
    });
    return menuItems;



 }

  String selectedValue = "1";

  @override
  void initState() {
    add("1");
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text("widget.title"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            loading?CircularProgressIndicator():DropdownButton(
              value: selectedValue,
              items: menuItems.map((DropdownMenuItem<String> items) {
                return items;
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? value) {
                setState(() {
                  add(value);
                });
              },
            )


      ],
    ),
  ),
);


}
```